# insert special character after n character in textfield extjs

Tags: javascript, events, key, extjs4.2

i have panel form in ExtJS and textfield inside and i try to insert symbol `.` after typing `*` in this textfield;
in this case when i type symbol `*` code insert symbol `.` but at the begining of textfield row;
how i can insert symbol `.` each time when i type symbol `*` at the begining
e.x.

```
now: i type: text* > result: .text*  
need: i type: text* > result text.*
```

```js
fieldLabel: 'name',
name: 'name',
id: 'name_id',
submitValue : true,
enableKeyEvents: true,
allowBlank: false,
listeners:{
keyup:function(field, event) {
var val = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name="name"]')[1].getValue();
//56 event key of "*"
if (event.getKey() == 56) {
field.setValue ('.' + val);
}                   
}
}
```

Comment: @FSDford, not at all, if i type > text* in result i have > text*.* i need > text.*

Comment: let valTrimmed = val.slice(0, val.length -1);  field.setValue ( valTrimmed + '.*');

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this line

```
field.setValue ('.' + val);
```

with these two lines.

```
let valTrimmed = val.slice(0, val.length -1); 
field.setValue ( valTrimmed + '.*');
```

Comment: can it possible to make symbol .(point) not visible for users?